# Add item to cart using POST requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

How would I add the item I got an id of to cart using post requests? This is my code:

```
post_headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
post_data = {"utf-8": "%E2%9C%93", "commit": "add to cart"}
url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/{productid}/add".format(productid=id)

add_to_cart = requests.post(url, headers=post_headers, data=post_data)
print(add_to_cart.content)
```

the specific product that I am trying to add to cart using post requests is : https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/shirts/zkmt62fz1/lg1ehyx3s

It accurately prints the item id in the console, but when I go to my cart, there is nothing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking in your cart in your browser. Usually a website will keep track of you as a user with cookies (e.g. a session id) and will with this info display your orders. If your are sending the order as a request in Python, then you will receive the cookies from the server in return in the response. Therefore if you are looking for the order in you browser, then you do not have the cookies from the Python response and the site will not recognise you as the same user.